# Display resolution mismatch with browser full screen

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

So I have 32" monitor with 1920x1080 resolution. I need to run my project on that kind of monitor in full screen. I write my project on html and all sizes are static for this resolution. But when I run projet in fullscreen (I use Chrome) the html tag stays at this size 1754x868. I reload the page and nothing. I have all drivers. What can I do?

Comment: If you put width : 100%; in you css for the html tag ?

Comment: any padding, margin? Does the content fill the whole height? Did you accidently zoom out in your browser?

Comment: width and height is 100% and yes the html fills whole screen but in developer tools the size is smaller and some content does not fit in.